# Google Chrome hidden user

Tags: google-chrome, browser, user

is it possible to create a Google chrome user that is hidden in the main users list and possibly accessible via a shortcut?
this way nobody can see the sites you are loged in and etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve it is to download and install [Chrome Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable) and stash it somewhere on your hard disk. It's independent from the main Chrome, so your profile will be as hidden as the Chrome Portable directory itself. You can move it to another directory just by copy-paste, because technically speaking it's not "installing" in system.

Answer (score 1):

In that way you can't stop anyone to see what have you seen on chrome but yes still you have a good thing called Incognito Mode. Always browse your sites there and you will be off record but you will not able to see any history yourself. IMO Incognito mode is the easiest and best way.